# Opening a certain page using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have a page-info.php file with content inside it:

```
    <div class="page">
            <a name="info" id="info"></a>
            <p>The content </p>

            <FORM><INPUT Type="button" VALUE="TAGASI" id="tagasi" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;"></FORM>


        </div>
```

In my index.php I have a button and when it's clicked it will then include the content on the page:

```
<a class="loe-siit" href="./info#info">Tahad rohkem teada?</a>
```

Now I would like to add another button which would show the content in english:

I've created a page called page-en.php:

```
    <div class="page">
    <a name="info" id="en"></a>
               <p> Content in english. </p>

<FORM><INPUT Type="button" VALUE="BACK" id="tagasi" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;"></FORM>


    </div>
```

Now how do get the content in page-en.php to show up the same way as the content in page-info.php does?

Test site: http://www.kogumelugu.ee/testing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your link to open index.php with a paremeter:

```
<a href="index.php?page=content_en">English</a>
```

And in the content part load the file according to the parameter you sent:

```
<?php
if($_GET['page']=='content_en') {
    include('page-en.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: This will make the content show up but it will be shown on top of all the other contents: http://www.kogumelugu.ee/testing/index.php?page=content_en If I would want it to show in the content area how would I achieve that?

Comment: With page-info.php this worked: `<?php if( !$page ): ?>
    <div class="sidebar">    

    </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
    
    <?php if( $page ): ?>
    <?php
     include('page-'.$page.'.php');
    ?>`

Comment: Alright, I just needed to add the `'en'` to my array `$pages = array('info', 'en');` and then change `<a href="index.php?page=content_en">English</a>` to `<a href="./en#en">In English</a>`